# Swift: Nested enum in generic that works with all types?

Tags: swift, generics, enums

A generic class can have an enum nested inside it:

```
 class MyClass<T> {

      enum MyEnum { 
      }

      var myEnum: MyEnum
 }
```

However when using the enum in a protocol the compiler is asking to fill in the type, merely to use the enum.

```
 protocol MyProtocol {
      var myEnum: MyClass.MyEnum { get }
      // Error: Reference to generic type 'MyClass' requires arguments in <...>
 }
```

Is it possible to define a nested enum inside a generic that works with all types?

Comment: No you can't. You have to define `MyEnum` outside of the generic class. Swift treats each specialized generic class as a distinct class on its own (using name mangling). So `MyClass<Int>.MyEnum` is different from `MyClass<Double>.MyEnum`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Any or AnyObject:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myEnum: MyClass<Any>.MyEnum{ get }
}
```